# is WebRTC using JavaScript available in Android 4(by any means)?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, webrtc, crosswalk

I am trying to make a JavaScript demo of WebRTC work in an Android 4 device.
I have tried using Crosswalk, and following the examples, but getUserMedia would not return video. Are there any examples of a setup working anywhere? By my knowledge, Crosswalk support is available from 4.0(4.1 in newer versions), and there are plugins for WebRTC and getUserMedia so I assumed it would work.

Regarding the exact Android versions, I would like to find out the minimum version possible, with versions 4.4, 4.2.2 and 4.0 being of most importance, but am also interested even if version 4.x is not possible.

Comment: I believe you can build Chromium with webrtc back to API 14. This may be not the latest head, and it could not be fully compatible with official Chrome running on a modern device.

Answer (score 1):

Chromium does not support Android 4.0 so CrossWalk decides to do not support Android 4.0 devices after version 20.

You can check this url to see more details.
https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/deprecate-40.html